# Live Linux CD/DVD with Bittorrent client, Java, Flash, VLC?

Tags: distribution-choice, java, adobe-flash, livecd, bittorrent

I'm looking for a live CD distribution that offers me fully featured environment for using Internet and OpenOffice (or some other office app compatible with M$ Word).

I thought about installing a mainstream distro like Ubuntu on USB Flash drive and adding the software myself, but I would have to get a fast 8 GB USB stick and I would lose the added security of CD/DVD -- that is the resistance to rootkits and the guarantee that I won't break anything on my system.

Comment: Ubuntu has Live CD version

Comment: I know, it doesn't have proprietary apps like Java or Flash though.

Comment: You could make your own custom live cd.

Comment: @Faheem: how? Do you have some link with instructions?

Comment: @user467799: If you google for "custom live cds", all the top hits are for Ubuntu. Notice the lack of the word "Linux". If you put that in, you should get slightly more targeted results. You could also try "building custom live linux cds" and similar variants. You need to know a little bit of stuff, but it is not difficult.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_remastering_software

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Linux Mint](http://www.linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=67) seems to be an exact match to what you're looking for! It includes allmost everything you need. OpenOffice, codecs, Firefox, *jockey* for easy installation of drivers (if needed), XChat, Pidgin, VLC, Transmission (BitTorrent client), Java, ... etc. I've been using it for about a year now, and it hasn't let me down since that time. One thing I would advice you though, is to just use *Linux Mint 10*, this is not the latest and greatest release, but *Linux Mint 11* seems to have some upstream issues, as it's based on Ubuntu, and Ubuntu is trowing everything around.
It's a Live DVD, but there's also a CD version, but it doesn't include some programs and codecs.

Answer (score 2):

Have you had a look at [Linux Mint](http://linuxmint.com/)? Never used it myself, but it does have a live DVD version including at least some codecs and OpenOffice. Package listing from DistroWatch [here](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=mint).